# Refresh Node.js page

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to refresh a Node.js page after a socket.io event ?

```
var messageDynamic = "Initial status";

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    response.end('The status is : ' + messageDynamic);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('UPDATE', function(message) {
        messageDynamic = message;

        // here I want to refresh the Node.js page (in order to update the message)

    });
```

Would it be possible that once 'messageDynamic' is updated, the node.js page is updated to ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Force refreshing webpage on the client-side with use of JS.

Comment: You don't need to refresh the page for updates if you emit an event with the necesary data to change the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your help but could you elaborate more please?

Answer (score 1):

As you have it the plain text page you get when you go to `/` in your browser requests the server once and then will no longer listen to any events from the server. In order to dynamically update it you will need to send back a full html page with socket.io client code to listen to it:

On the server you would do:

```
   socket.on('UPDATE', function(message) {
        messageDynamic = message;

        // Send event to every socket.io client
        io.emit('message', message);
    });
```

On the client you would have a corresponding

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('message', function(message){
    // Do stuff to the page
})
```

See http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ for a more complete example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks but at the "// Do stuff to the page" position, it's on the client side, how could I do modify the server main page ?

Comment: If you need to change `messageDynamic` on the server, then doing `socket.emit("UPDATE", "new message")` on a client would change it. But, client's won't refresh unless they are also listening for an event.

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear, I want that once messageDynamic is updated on the server side (which is the case with my initial code), the "    response.end('The status is : ' + messageDynamic)" is updated or executed again.

Comment: The `response.end(...)` line will only be run when a user explicitly goes to that url or refreshes. You can not force it to refresh from the server without adding code to the page you send to the browser that waits for a message before refreshing.